# JS Encryption w/ HTML

Tags: javascript

This *should* add the encoded text to the HTML but doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
var i=0,j=0,k=0;
var letters=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
function gibberish(string, list) {
document.innerHTML +="<p>";
for(var j=0;j<string.length;j++){
document.innerHTML += letters[(letters.indexOf(string.charAt(k))*list[(j%8)]+list[((j+1)%8)])%8];
k++;
}
document.innerHTML += "</p>";
}
var array = [];
var ptxt;
for(i=1;i<9;i++) {
array.push(prompt("enter a number (less than 10 preferably!)"));
}
ptxt = prompt("ok now enter a string");
gibberish(ptxt,array);
</script>
```

What am I doing incorrectly, et cetera?

Comment: As a note, this "encryption" is pretty trivial to break so I hope it's not protecting anything important. You should have a function that does the encoding, and a separate function that takes care of injecting into the page if necessary. This seems to do both, which confuses the code.

Comment: @tadman Well hey -- try turning "nehkfcxw" into "language". There are 10^8 possible keys, and it's basically a simplified NLFSR (nonlinear feedback shift register) except without the feedback part. And no, it's protecting translated Wikipedia articles that already seem like `gibberish()` because of how Google Translate works. :)

Comment: You make that sound like a big number but it's really not. If you need to actually encrypt something, please, please *do not roll your own encryption*.

Comment: Again, separating the encryption part from the document alteration part would help narrow down the problem. Your function is trying to do everything at once which makes it way harder to test and debug. `gibberish()` should do the encoding. `updateTextField(...)` should set that display value or whatever, but honestly jQuery's `$('#output').html(...)` is the answer here.

Comment: @tadman I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document does not have an `innerHTML` property. You have to select an element inside it - perhaps the `document.body`. You also shouldn't concatenate unbalanced tags - concatenate a balanced HTML string all at once, when it's ready:

```js
var i = 0,
  j = 0,
  k = 0;
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function gibberish(string, list) {
  let str = "<p>";
  for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
    str += letters[(letters.indexOf(string.charAt(k)) * list[(j % 8)] + list[((j + 1) % 8)]) % 8];
    k++;
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += str + "</p>";
}
var array = [];
var ptxt;
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  array.push(prompt("enter a number (less than 10 preferably!)"));
}
ptxt = prompt("ok now enter a string");
gibberish(ptxt, array);
```

But concatenating with the `innerHTML` of an element is usually a bad idea - it'll force the whole container to be re-parsed, and will corrupt any listeners the container may have inside it. To avoid those problems, it might be better to create a `<p>` and use `appendChild` instead.

You can also create the `letters` array less repetitively by iterating over key codes.

It would also be good to make sure that the inputted numbers are actually numbers - you can use a `do`-`while` loop to verify them:

```js
const letters = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + i));
function gibberish(string, list) {
  let k = 0;
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  for (let j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
    p.textContent += letters[(letters.indexOf(string.charAt(k)) * list[(j % 8)] + list[((j + 1) % 8)]) % 8];
    k++;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
var array = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  let num = null;
  do {
    prompt("enter a number (less than 10 preferably!)");
  } while (num === null);
  array.push(num);
}
gibberish(prompt("ok now enter a string"), array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`document` not have `innerHTML` property. try to use `document.body.innerHTML`